# How to inform Vaadin table about the change of cell contents size

Tags: vaadin

I have Vaadin table with a custom cell renderer (using addGeneratedColumn). It renders some component which can change it's height (collapse or expand), when a user clicks on some button. The problem is: how to inform table, that it's cell contents have changed their size? If I don't inform table anyhow, it assumes that sizes of components in cells are the same when they were rendered at first time and some visual bugs appear.

Comment: could you add at least some schematics, how the components are arranged?  what vaadin version?  as some first attempt to an answer: have you tried marking the table dirty after the visual change?  usually changing the `visible` property would also propagate to the parent, so this should not be needed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible....

Comment: does table.refreshRowCache() work?